# URL alias in page.tpl.php

Tags: 6, path-aliases

I try to make link 'Mobile version' on site page site.com/page. This link leads to this page but on subdomain m.site.com/page. 
I use page.tpl.php. I try to write this.

```
<a href="http://m.site.com/<?php print drupal_get_path_alias();?>">Mobile version</a>
```

`<?php print drupal_get_path_alias();?>` prints nothing. What's wrong? Maybe there is some more elegant and right way to solve this?

Comment: [drupal_get_path_alias](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/6.x) requires at least one argument for Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only work for Drupal 7. As you are using Drupal 6, please pass the current url as argument.

```php
print drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
```